# Does assetlinks.json file for Android App Links have a size limit like the iOS counterpart?

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, android-app-links

In order to only allow authorized apps to open `https` links, Android has [App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations), and iOS has [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-universal-links-in-your-app). In both, one needs to upload a file, viz. `assetlinks.json` for Android and `apple-app-site-association` file for iOS on `https://domain.name/.well-known/` path. I could find that for iOS, [the file size can be max 128 KB](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#:%7E:text=For%20apps%20that%20run%20in%20iOS%209.3.1%20and%20later%2C%20the%20uncompressed%20size%20of%20the%20apple%2Dapp%2Dsite%2Dassociation%20file%20must%20be%20no%20greater%20than%20128%20KB%2C%20regardless%20of%20whether%20the%20file%20is%20signed), however, couldn't find any such information for `assetlinks.json`. Is there a size limit for it?

Answer (score 1):

Officially there is no limit mentioned any where in the document. But when I have tried using Branch.io common link in my app, the app links verification was failing when app was installed. Figured out the same from the logs and the reason for the same was read timeout.

The file hosted here is very huge and mentions a lot of apps which support Branch's bnc.lt links.

https://bnc.lt/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Which causes it to fail as Android fails to verify the same during installation and hence also causes other links configured also not to work.

A file link with just 8-10 apps won't be that huge and won't cause a problem.